# Underscore (_) gets being converted to section sign (§) - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, sms

I'm developing a windows service application that gets data from MS SQL server 2008 and then sends SMS using that data. However, when I receive the SMS, all underscores are converted into section signs. The collation of the database is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and the datatype of the column is nvarchar(MAX).

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is? I have searched about collations and charsets but I haven't found a solution to this problem.

Comment: How you are send SMS?

Comment: serial port using AT commands...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I set the `Encoding` property of my `SerialPort` to `utf-8`.

```
With spPort
    .PortName = "COM23"
    .Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
    .Open()
End With
```

Comment: We faced this weird situation too, now I'm going to add these lines to my php code as you said . mb_convert_encoding(MESSAGE,"UTF-8")